# ESRI Flex Viewer 2.4 - How Can I Remove The Header (or UI Component that holds the HeaderController Widget)

Tags: arcgis-flex-viewer

I am trying to make some modifications to the general layout of the Flex Viewer.  As part of these modifications, I am trying to remove the Header altogether.

I removed the HeaderControllerWidget from the config.xml - thinking the map should now occupy the entire browser.   But now I just get empty white space where the HeaderController was, leading me to believe some UI component must be defined elsewhere to hold the HeaderController widget.

I have searched through the code trying to find this component with no luck.  Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can remove Header altogether?  I want the map to occupy the entire browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured this one out.  The map node in the config.xml has a 'top' attribute.  By default, it is set at 70.  Changed it to 0, and now the map fills the whole browser.

Comment: did u succeed to add another container for widgets icons